# Android: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created

Tags: android, android-asynctask, realm, android-thread

So inside a `IntentService`, the app maybe active or inactive , `onHandleIntent` gets called , where I have placed this below code.This is where I store the data into realm.

```
 Realm realm = null;
    try { 
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {

                for (AppItem item : items) {
                    AppItem item2 = realm.createObject(AppItem.class, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                    item2.mName = item.mName;
                    item2.mCount = item.mCount;
                    item2.mUsageTime = item.mUsageTime;
                }
            }
        });
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
```

Then I am trying to access it in `onPostExecute` in `AsyncTask`, In `doInBackground`, I am getting the `RealmResults<AppItem>`, then storing it into `List <AppItem>` and sending it to `onPostExecute` where this code is placed. `appItems` is ReamObject here

```
 Realm backgroundRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            backgroundRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    for (AppItem item : appItems) { 
 //getting error here   if (item.mUsageTime <= 0) continue;
                        mTotal += item.mUsageTime;
                        item.mCanOpen = mPackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(item.mPackageName) != null;


               }
              }
            });
```

Both I have done using `executeTransactionAsync`, still I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the error message: Once you obtain any Realm objects on 1 thread, they can ONLY be accessed on that thread. Any access on other threads will throw that exception.

"doInBackground" from AsyncTask is run on a background thread. "onPostExecute" is run on the UI thread. So here you get Realm objects on a background thread, and try to access them on the UI thread => Exception.

You should either do everything on the background thread, or everything on the UI thread.

If you're doing a very complex query, i suggest using "findAllAsync" on the RealmQuery, as this will run the query on a background thread, and move them over to the main thread, but it's handled internally by Realm in a safe manner.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> for (AppItem item : appItems) {
> ```

If `appItems` contains managed RealmObjects that you obtained from a RealmResults on the UI thread, then accessing them will fail on the background thread.

`realm.executeTransactionAsync((realm) -> {` gives you a Realm as parameter that is running on Realm's thread executor, so *that* must be used to obtain managed RealmResults/RealmObjects inside the transaction.

So you need to re-query the objects inside `realm.executeTransactionAsync` if the objects are managed.

```
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                for (AppItem item : realm.where(AppItem.class).findAll()) {
```

Comment: Thanks, and  I have read your blogs on Realm! They are really good

Answer (score 0):

I have found same error, because it has a different thread.

I solved the problem in a way :

```
// Repository Class
scope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
     // Your Code
}

// View Model
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    // Your Code
}
```